# Prisma: What would be the best way to create relationships between 3 tables?

Tags: database, postgresql, prisma, prisma2

I have the following models.How can I create a relationship for these tables so that I can get the roles associated with group and group associated with roles.One group will have multiple roles.
Groups and Roles will be added separately though.Only after the Group is added can the roles be associated with them

```
model groups {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  group_name  String?  @unique
}

model roles {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  role_name   String?  @unique
}

model group_role_association {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  group_id    Int
  role_id     Int
}
```

Comment: Hi, Make id as pk on each table, later u can add fks in group_role_association

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a use case for an [implicit relation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations#implicit-many-to-many-relations). This is a feature of Prisma that allows you to model a m-n relatinshiop between to tables *without* managing a relation table (in your example, I read `group_role_association` to be a relation table rather than an actual "model")?

```
model groups {
  id         Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  groups_name  String
  roles      roles[]
}

model roles {
  id          Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  role_name String
  groups    groups[]
}
```

Also, I'd actually recommend you to use Prisma's naming conventions (i.e. spell model names in singular form and PascalCase notation):

```
model Group {
  id    Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  name  String
  roles Role[]
}

model Role {
  id     Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name   String
  groups Group[]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However new Groups and Roles will be added separately though.Only after the Group is added can the roles be associated with them.Not sure if the above would help in that case.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't help in that case :) you can create roles and groups separately and when the time comes you add the role to a group (or the other way around) using the nested write `connect` API.